# Error pygame al crear un ejecutable de un proyecto con Pyinstaller

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, pyinstaller

El problema que se manifiesta en consola al ejecutarse es el siguiente:

```
pygame 1.9.6
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pingpongmania.py", line 643, in <module>
  File "pingpongmania.py", line 620, in main
  File "pingpongmania.py", line 16, in load_music 
pygame.error
[11736] Failed to execute script pingpongmania
```

el modulo `pingpongmania.py` tiene lo siguiente:

```py
import pygame as pg
import time as t
import sys
import os

#...

def load_music(name, dirname):
    path = os.path.join(dirname, name)
    pg.mixer.music.load(path) # linea 16

#...

def main():
    global TITLE_S

    # inicializar
    pg.init()
    pg.mixer.init()

    # ventana y nombre
    screen = pg.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
    pg.display.set_caption('PingPongMania')
    icon = load_image('icon.png', DIR_IMG, alpha=True)

    # cargo cancion
    load_music('Fighting is not an option.mp3', DIR_SND) # linea 620

# ...
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main() # linea 643
```

Las constantes `DIR_IMG` y `DIR_SND` son constantes que guardan los nombres de las carpetas de imagenes y sonido respectivamente. Al probar `pingpongmania.py` en consola y en un IDE funcionan perfecto, asi que llegue a la conclusion que se trata de la generacion del ejecutable, aunque no tengo idea de como se genera este error.
Utilizo Pyinstaller para crearlo.

Comment: Puedes indicar cuales son las líneas 16, 620 y 643 en tu bloque de código? Adicionalmente, intenta usar  `pyinstaller --onefile pingpongmania.py`. Verifica esta respuesta en Stack Overflow, también: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36456473/11649862

Comment: Listo, puse las lineas en la pregunta principal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok el problema se debia a que PyInstaller se crashea archivos .mp3, utilizando archivos ogg o wav funciona correctamente. Tambien es importante la forma de obtener el path de los archivos de la siguiente manera:

```py
import pygame as pg
import time as t
import sys
import os

#...

def load_music(name, dirname):
    path = os.path.dirname(__file__) # obtengo el directorio entero
    path = os.path.join(path, dirname, name) # lo uno al resto
    pg.mixer.music.load(path) # linea 16

#...

def main():
    global TITLE_S

    # inicializar
    pg.init()
    pg.mixer.init()

    # ventana y nombre
    screen = pg.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
    pg.display.set_caption('PingPongMania')
    icon = load_image('icon.png', DIR_IMG, alpha=True)

    # cargo cancion
    load_music('Fighting is not an option.mp3', DIR_SND) # linea 620

# ...
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main() # linea 643
```

Y de esta forma nos aseguramos que pueda hallarse correctamente

Como una alternativa a este problema utilice auto-py-to-exe en vez de Pyinstaller con Python 3.7.0, instale los packages correspondientes en un entorno y logre completar el ejecutable, para el resto de personas que tengan un problemas similar.